# How to move old Java Projects from new Worskpace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I make my java projects from my old workspace to my new one? Re-installed Eclipse and now I don't know how to make the old ones to work.

Comment: Something like File > Import ?

Comment: Solved it already. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select "File" -> "Import..." from the menu
2. Select the item "General" -> "Existing Projects into Workspace"
3. Next to "Select root directory:" enter the path to the projects you want to add to the workspace
4. If you want to actually copy the files over (you'll have to delete the originals later), tick "Copy projects into workspace" (under "Options"). If you want to keep them where they are then untick it.
5. If you choose not to copy the files then I recommend removing the projects from the old workspace (without deleting them!), as having a project in two workspaces may cause problems later.

Answer (score 0):

> you can import them into eclipse. Click `File` then `import` then `general` then `Existing projects into workspace` blablabla.....